# SQL injection in Rails in Where Clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-injection

I have following line which was suspected of SQL injection by a static code analyzer:

```
Admin.joins(:accounts_admins).where(user_id: params[:user_u
ser_id], "members.account_id" => @account.id).first
```

To me, it looks safe as its using parameterized query. Let me know if anyone think otherwise.

Comment: The docs answer this question: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct; Rails will convert the WHERE clause to use bound parameters and thus avoid the risk of SQL injection.

That said, as a best practice, you should leverage strong_parameters or some other form of parameter validation. As your code is written, a nil value will cause Rails to insert a `WHERE user_id IS NULL` expression. That's likely not a problem here, but in some cases it can cause unauthorized access.